# xcode 5 - debug on device failed using jailcoder

Tags: iphone, xcode

Using xcode 5.1.1, and trying to debug my app on a jailbroken iphone 4 (7.1.2).
I installed Jailcoder (from the facebook page) and patched both my xcode and my project with it.
The project is just a simple view application (trying to get that to work first).
I run the app using my iphone as the build setting, the app loads on my phone but then it exits with

```
2014-07-28 16:00:42.831 testLiveDebug[11384:60b] otherApps (null)
```

Opening the console in the organizer i see this error:

```
Jul 28 15:51:45 my-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.debug.testLiveDebug[0xe02e][11348]) <Error>: (UIKitApplication:com.debug.testLiveDebug[0xe02e]) Exited with code: 45
Jul 28 15:51:45 my-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.debug.testLiveDebug[0xe02e]) <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.debug.testLiveDebug[0xe02e]) Throttling respawn: Will start in 2147483641 seconds
Jul 28 15:51:45 my-iPhone com.apple.debugserver-310.2[11346] <Warning>: 38 +6.392165 sec [2c52/1307]: error: ::read ( -1, 0x35a9ec, 18446744069414585344 ) => -1 err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009)
Jul 28 15:51:45 my-iPhone com.apple.debugserver-310.2[11346] <Warning>: Exiting.
Jul 28 15:51:45 my-iPhone backboardd[11188] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.debug.testLiveDebug[0xe02e]' exited abnormally with exit status 45
```

I have Appsync for 7.0+ and also tried with AppSync Unified....but still i get the same error.

In the past (ios6) this whole process worked fine with jailcoder.

Any idea why i cant live debug on the device ?

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Resupported 4+ was causing the error....after i uninstalled it everything was working fine.